# Такой способ создания объектов резонный?

Tags: node.js, javascript

Я создаю объекты пользователей следующим образом:

```
function player(world, uid) {
  this.id = uid;
  this.world = world;

  if(this.id > 10) {
    this.world.players[id] = this;
  }
};

// -- участок кода обьекта класса world --
  new player(this, 9); // < - Как я понимаю этот объект через некоторое время удалиться из памяти, так как в нём нету никаких событий и нет ссылок на него
  new player(this, 11); // < - Этот будет существовать
// --
```

Можно ли так делать? (в плане производительности и утечки памяти итд.) Или посоветуете другой способ?

Comment: это что такое:

     this.world.players[id] = this;
     this.world.players[11].world.players[12].world.players[13].world.players[11]....

Comment: > нём нету никаких событий и нет ссылок на него

Раз так, то наверное ты его и не используешь, верно? И от того что он будет собран сборщиком ничего не случится.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы сделал как-то так

```
function Player( uid ) {
  this.id = uid;
}

function World() {
  this.players = {};
  this
    .registerPlayer( new Player(9) )
    .registerPlayer( new Player(11) )
  // ....
}

World.prototype = {
  registerPlayer : function( player ) {
    if(player.id > 10) {
      this.players[ player.id ] = player;
    }
    return this;
  },
  unregisterPlayer : function( player ) {
    delete this.players[ player.id ];
    return this;
  }
  // ...
}

var GameWorld = new World();
```

Если игрока больше не существует либо он больше не нужен, естественно, его нужно очищать.

Comment: как вариант так:

    _.extend(World.prototype, { 
        registerPlayer: ...,
        unregisterPlayer: ...,
    });

не важно какой extend, хоть jQuery'вский, хоть самописный